# C++ - how to resolve function overload ambiguity

Tags: c++, c++11

consider following simple class (please no debates about usefulness):

```
class Container
{
    public:
        Container(const long long &val); //construct the container with a long long
        Container(const long double &val); //construct the container with a long double
        Container(const std::string &val); //construct the container with a string
        Container(const Container &val); //copy constructor, implemented as copy and swap

        //explicit conversions are also included for other data types
        explicit operator long long() const; //explicit conversion to long long

    private:
        int dataType;
        void *data;
};
```

And to construct the object, I would call:

```
Container cont(20); //or
Container cont2("some string");
```

But the compiler tells me he cannot resolve the ambiguous constructor call for int.

This leads me to my question, what is the best and cleanest way to resolve this ambiguity.
Should I use some sort of templatized constructor looking somewhat like this:

```
Container<int> cont(20);
```

Or use an explicit cast or a dummy parameter?

The templatized way looks like a compromise I could accept, though I'm sure the actual call would look different.

Well thanks for any insights!

Comment: `Container cont(double(20)); Container cont(int(20));` etc etc...

Comment: `Container(int o) : { /* do same stuff as for long long */ }` also don't pass ints and floats by const reference - that's at most less efficient

Comment: I like how your simple code comments are completely lying...

Comment: What do you mean by that @LightnessRacesinOrbit?

Comment: `Container cont(20.0)` will resolve the ambiguity, any way I think it's better to remove the `int` overload of the constructor as the float will do fine except if you don't want so, what's your goal of this class ?

Comment: It is sort of a container which may hold an `int`, a `float` or a `string` value. Merely for educational reasons, than for real world problems. Therefore leaving the `int` constructor out an always calling `Container cont(20.0)` would not satisfy me, there muste be a way to do this...

Comment: Alternatively for long long: `Container cont(20LL)`

Comment: @MäxMüller I think that @LightnessRacesInOrbit is referring to the fact that your comments say things like `//construct the container with an int` when, and this is obviously compiler dependent, a `long long` doesn't always equal an `int`. In fact in MSVC it is equivalent to `__int64`. Or `long double` which is not a `float` as the comment says.

Comment: I see that's a bit ambiguous itself, but as far as I understand it a `long long` is an integer with a guaranteed minimum width of `64 bits` and a `long double` is a float with double precision. I will edit the code though and please correct me if I got that wrong!

Comment: @MäxMüller I see where you are going with that... but `int` is actually a data type as well, and so is `float`. So when you use those, people will assume you are referencing the primitive type directly. For instance, for MSVC 2013: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

Comment: @RyanP Yeah I see what the problem is with my terminology (kind of ironic talking about ambiguity). Anyways, I edited the question to resolve this misunderstanding. Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: Yes, you have a constructor taking a `long long` documented as taking an `int`, and a constructor taking a `long double` documented as taking a `float`, lol

Answer (score 3):

Just add a constructor for `int` that disambiguates it:

```
Container(int i)
: Container(static_cast<long long>(i)) // or whichever version you want
                                       // to call
{ }
```

Comment: Alternatively casting before passing to the constructor should work: `Container cont(static_cast<long long>(20));`

Comment: Casting right before indeed works, but I would like it if that would not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a constructor templated by the type:

```
class Container {
    template <class T> Container (const T& rhs);
};
```

See the implementation of "any" in Boost for an example similar to what you want to do:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/any.html